# Cybersource Secure Acceptance in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cybersource

I recently developed e-commerce site using WordPress. I used CyberSource plugin for payments but I cannot test the functionality.

When I click on payment it display an error:

```
401: Error Connecting to the API
rmsg: Authentication Failed
```

What should I do? Does new CyberSource plugin supports secure acceptance?

Comment: Hi, what is the plugin you are using?

Comment: i'm currently using woocommerce new cybersource plugin (cybersource 2.0 i think)